# ProgressDialog that runs almost

Tags: java, android, progressdialog

Everything works except one, pg1 not show up, but i see "wait" and "done".
Of course method works too, just this progressDialog not show up.
I have no idea why.
Someone can check this?

I

```
private ProgressDialog pg1;
```

II

```
 pg1 = new ProgressDialog(this);
   pg1.setMessage("download...");
```

III

```
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {

                     pg1.show();


            new BackgroundJob1().execute();
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "wait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



        }
    });
```

IV

```
 private class BackgroundJob1 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>

    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


        publishProgress();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            pg1.cancel();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            myMethod();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Right now, the code snippets currently posted don't really make sense and are partial implementations that won't compile.  Please post more complete code, so we can better help.

Comment: what exactly ? the rest of the code is not therefore

Answer (score 0):

Try use ProgressDialog in UIThread :)

Comment: something more :) ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but the problem might you pass wrong context to your ProgressDialog. Maybe try new ProgressDialog(MapsActivity.this).

Comment: And you should pass context in your show() method :)